# Tortoise SVN log -limit or something similar

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, command-line-arguments

I am trying to debug a code error a work associate committed to our SVN, and to do that I need to step through the logs, but using svn -log dumps the whole list, which makes me unable to view everything, as scrolling up ends much before the log does. Using the limit  command does not work very well, either. I can have it show me the last, say, 10 commits, but is there a way to continue to the *next* 10 after? Or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `more` command?

```
svn -log | more
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use --limit option for svn log on command line.

```
svn log --limit 10
```

On Command line it's really useful to use more or less depending if you are on windows or unix.

In TortoiseSVN you have usually a button for ["next 100" or 500](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) depending on how it is [configured](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-dia-dialogs). You should go via [Repo-Browser](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html).

Comment: That is what I am using right now, but if I am using the command line, is there a way to see the NEXT 10 after the initial 10?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "scrolling up", I assume you're talking about the windows command-line "dos window" output buffer?  If so, you're "doing it wrong".
You should redirect the log to a text file, then use a competent editor such as Notepad++ (can handle huge files, good searching, fast) or even the lowly Windows notepad.

So if your command that you run is:

```
svn -log
```

you should re-direct to a file such as:

```
svn -log > c:\SomeFolderThatICanFind\svnOut.txt
```

Comment: Ah yes. Not exactly necessary for my current situation, but still a value for me to know in the future, thanks!